# references class "Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\UnitOfWork" but no such service exists

Tags: symfony, doctrine-mongodb

I'm currently using Symfony 4 with Doctrine MongoDB Bundle, following the instruction from this link: 
[DoctrineMongoDBBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#content_wrapper). So, I have a UserDocument:

**src/Document/UserDocument.php**

```
/** @MongoDB\Document(collection="user", repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository") */
class UserDocument
{

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     * @var ObjectId
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string", name="first_name")
     * @var string
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string", name="middle_name")
     * @var string
     */
    private $middleName;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string", name="last_name")
     * @var string
         */
        private $lastName;
    }
```

**src/Repository/UserRepository.php**

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentRepository;
class UserRepository extends DocumentRepository
{

}
```

**src/Controller/Content.php**

class Content extends Controller

```
{

    /**
     * @Route("/content", name="content")
     * @param UserRepository $user
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(UserRepository $user)
    {
        $user->findAll();
        return new Response();
    }


}
```

So, after running the content page, I got the following error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\UserRepository": argument "$uow" of method "__construct()" references class "Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\UnitOfWork" but no such service exists.

The DocumentRepository constructor looks like this:

```
public function __construct(DocumentManager $dm, UnitOfWork $uow, ClassMetadata $classMetadata)
    {
        parent::__construct($dm, $uow, $classMetadata);
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Repository shouldn't be Services, but if you want to keep it that way, just Autowire the `DocumentManager` and get the uow and classmetdata from the Document Manager.

`UnitOfWork` and `ClassMetadata` can't be autowired

Do something like that in your `UserRepository`, it should work.

```
public function __construct(DocumentManager $dm)
{
    $uow = $dm->getUnitOfWork();
    $classMetaData = $dm->getClassMetadata(User::class);
    parent::__construct($dm, $uow, $classMetaData);
}
```

Comment: Already solved it long time ago, just like your answer. btw, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to exclude your repository class from autowiring. Example here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html

In case you want your repository class as a service you should do it using a factory service.